# How to sort buckets of script aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to use `format` property for `terms` aggregation with date fields, but I face 2 major issues:

1. For normal `aggs`; I might get 2 buckets with the same `key_as_string` if I used wide period like month or year, for example, if I used `MMMM` format I'll get:

```
    {
        "key": 1427922000000,
        "key_as_string": "April",
        "doc_count": 20
    },
    {
        "key": 1428094800000,
        "key_as_string": "April",
        "doc_count": 20
    }
```

2. I can't use `format` property for `terms` inside `composite` sources, It'll throw an error.

So, I used custom `script` to solve this issue, by converting dates into string:

```
"terms": {
    "script": {
        "source": """
            // check if document has this field to avoid errors
            if(!doc.containsKey(params.field) || doc[params.field].toString() == "[]") return "";
            // Get each field value as string
            String datetime = doc[params.field].value.toString();
            // Cast datetime into ZonedDateTime to use format function
            ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(datetime);
            // Create format object based on user option
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(params.format);
            // return formatted date
            return zdt.format(formatter);
        """,
        "params": {
            "field": "Order Date",
            "format": "MMMM"
        }
    },
    "order": {
        "_key": "asc"
    }
}
```

It works as expected, but I face an issue with ordering by `_key`, because elastic treats each bucket key as string, so; it orders months like:

```
{
    "key": "April",
    "doc_count": 90
},
{
    "key": "August",
    "doc_count": 46
},
{
    "key": "December",
    "doc_count": 61
},
{
    "key": "February",
    "doc_count": 67
}
```

My question is: how can make custom order for aggs or return script value as `key_as_string` so elastic will sort by `key`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using nested `min` aggregations for same field and tell **elasticsearch** to order buckets based on `min` value.

The point of using `min` is getting date value that represents formatted bucket so **elastic** can order based on it.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "Order Date": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": """
            // check if document has this field to avoid errors
            if(doc.containsKey(params.field) && doc[params.field].toString() != "[]") {
              // Get each field value as string
              String datetime = doc[params.field].value.toString();
              // Cast datetime into ZonedDateTime to use format function
              ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(datetime);
              // Create format object based on user option
              DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(params.format);
              // return formatted date
              return zdt.format(formatter);
            }
          """,
          "params": {
            "field": "Order Date",
            "format": "MMMM"
          }
        },
        "size": 10000,
        "order": {
          "SORT_BY_DATE": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "SORT_BY_DATE": {
          "min": {
            "field": "Order Date"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will generate:

```
{
    "key": "January",
    "doc_count": 64,
    "SORT_BY_DATE": {
        "value": 1420149600000,
        "value_as_string": "2015-01-01T22:00:00.000Z"
    }
},
{
    "key": "February",
    "doc_count": 67,
    "SORT_BY_DATE": {
        "value": 1422828000000,
        "value_as_string": "2015-02-01T22:00:00.000Z"
    }
},
{
    "key": "March",
    "doc_count": 32,
    "SORT_BY_DATE": {
        "value": 1425247200000,
        "value_as_string": "2015-03-01T22:00:00.000Z"
    }
},
{
    "key": "April",
    "doc_count": 90,
    "SORT_BY_DATE": {
        "value": 1427922000000,
        "value_as_string": "2015-04-01T21:00:00.000Z"
    }
},
{
    "key": "May",
    "doc_count": 85,
    "SORT_BY_DATE": {
        "value": 1430514000000,
        "value_as_string": "2015-05-01T21:00:00.000Z"
    }
}
```

And I ignore value of `SORT_BY_DATE` aggs like it's not exist.